# xgboost: Huge logloss despite reasonable accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, cross-entropy, bigdata

I train a xgboost classifier on a binary classification problem. It produces 70% accurate predictions. Yet logloss is very big at 9.13. I suspect that might be because a few predictions are very much off the target, but I do not understand why it happens - other people report much better logloss (0.55 - 0.6) on the same data with xgboost.

```
from readCsv import x_train, y_train
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, log_loss
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

seed=7
test_size=0.09

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x_train, y_train, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

# fit model no training data
model = XGBClassifier(max_depth=5,
                      learning_rate=0.02,
                      objective= 'binary:logistic',
                      n_estimators = 5000)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))

ll = log_loss(y_test, y_pred)
print("Log_loss: %f" % ll)
print(model)
```

produces following output:

```
Accuracy: 73.54%
Log_loss: 9.139162
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1,
       gamma=0, learning_rate=0.02, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=5000, nthread=-1,
       objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True, subsample=1)
```

Anyone knows reasons for my high logloss? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you compute accuracy with rounded predictions but compute your log loss without rounded predictions. Did you try checking your accuracy without rounding the values?

Comment: @rafaelvalle Tested just now without rounding: it produced exactly the same number - 73.54%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution: use model.predict_proba(), not model.predict()

This reduced logloss from 7+ to 0.52, which is in expected range. model.predict() was outputing values of huge magnitude like 1e18, it seems it needed to go through some function which would make it a valid probability score (between 0 and 1).